# как сделать темную тему на сайте?

Tags: html, css

как сделать темную/светлую тему на сайте с переключателем, и чтобы после обновления страницы, тема сохранялась?

Comment: Сохранять выбор пользователя в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: я просто не оч шарю может кто то мог бы поделиться кодом или еще что то

Comment: Выбирайте любую ссылку: [Make white/dark theme localStorage](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+white%2Fdark+theme+localStorage&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUA951UA951&oq=make+white%2Fdark+theme+localStorage&aqs=chrome..69i57.110j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)